# Tensorflow not getting imported on sublime text but it does on vim

Tags: python

It throws this error whenever I import it on sublime, no idea why

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

It is generated at this function in array_ops of tensorflow

```
# Aliases for some automatically-generated names.
# pylint: disable=protected-access
@deprecation.deprecated(
    "2016-11-30",
    "This op will be removed after the deprecation date. "
    "Please switch to tf.setdiff1d().")
def listdiff(x, y, out_idx=None, name=None):
  return gen_array_ops.list_diff(x, y, out_idx, name)

##################Type error occurs for this line################
listdiff.__doc__ = gen_array_ops.list_diff.__doc__ + "\n" + listdiff.__doc__
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're using to execute code on these editors? Can you also share the code that causes this exception?

Comment: Of the top of my head, I think that an issue like this might happen if you have some plugins that are running python and they are pointing to different versions of python. You may have to configure them to point to the right version/virtual environment for python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I just had to update my version of tensorflow as my previous one was broken.